# Matrix with delta function

Tags: matrices

I need to prove a commutator relation, but I'm getting stuck at the definition of the matrices.

$(L_{ab})_{cd} = \delta_{ac} \delta_{bd} - \delta_{ad} \delta_{bc}$ with $a<b$ and $a, b \in 1,2,3,4$.
What does this definition of the matrix mean? Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me illustrate in the case $2\times2$.

The matrix $L_{ab}$ would be 
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
\delta_{a1}\delta_{b1}-\delta_{a1}\delta_{b1}
&\delta_{a1}\delta_{b2}-\delta_{a2}\delta_{b1}\\
\delta_{a2}\delta_{b1}-\delta_{a1}\delta_{b2}
&\delta_{a2}\delta_{b2}-\delta_{a2}\delta_{b2}
\end{array}\right]
.$$

Then for $L_{11}$ we have
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
\delta_{11}\delta_{11}-\delta_{11}\delta_{11}
&\delta_{11}\delta_{12}-\delta_{12}\delta_{11}\\
\delta_{12}\delta_{11}-\delta_{11}\delta_{12}
&\delta_{12}\delta_{12}-\delta_{12}\delta_{12}
\end{array}\right]
=
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0&0\\
0&0
\end{array}\right]
$$

But for $L_{12}$
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
\delta_{11}\delta_{21}-\delta_{11}\delta_{21}
&\delta_{11}\delta_{22}-\delta_{12}\delta_{21}\\
\delta_{12}\delta_{21}-\delta_{11}\delta_{22}
&\delta_{12}\delta_{22}-\delta_{12}\delta_{22}
\end{array}\right]
=
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0&1\\
-1&0
\end{array}\right]
$$

Comment: Thank you! But what do the second indices 'cd' mean. So, I'd understand it if it was only $L_{ab}$, but I'm very confused about the $(L_{ab})_{cd}$ notation.

Comment: the $cd$ indexes determines the entry in the $c$-row and $d$-column of the matrix $L_{ab}$

Comment: you oughtta use that $\delta_{ij}=1$ when $i=j$ and $\delta_{ij}=0$ when $i\neq j$... this is the famous *delta Kronecker*

Comment: Thanks, now I got it! So basically I could build this matrix in 4x4 by following your idea. Now I have to prove this commutator relation:

$\left[L_{ab}, L_{cd} \right] = \delta_{ad}L_{bc} + \delta_{bc}L_{ab} - \delta_{ac} L_{bd} - \delta_{bd} L_{ac}$. DO you have any hint on proving this? I guess writing out the matrices and doing the multiplication is pretty straight forward and not so nice.